# Error when running node script , Cannot find module 'mongodb/node_modules/bson'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

Trying to populate a mongo db with Employee data with the help of mongoose. When running as: node populate_db.js  it throws an error saying

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb/node_modules/bson'
```

not able to check the database value as the database also seems to be empty.

here is my package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "hr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "first node app server",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/pereiraryan/domains.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "domains"
  ],
  "author": "ryan pereira",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/pereiraryan/domains/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/pereiraryan/domains#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.5.0",
    "mongoose-post-find": "0.0.2",
    "colors": "^1.1.2",
    "debug": "0.7.4",
    "express": "4.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^3.8.11"
  } ,
  "scripts": {
    "populate": "node ./bin/populate_db"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your mongoose to version 4.2.9 right in you package json file.
Power up your json file in an editor and change the version to 'this'. The type 'npm install' in that directory you have your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -g node-gyp 
cd /to/your/project-folder
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

try doing this
also

```
do npm install inside node_modules/mongodb.
```

Comment: This would mean i will be reinstalling all the node modules. and then again install it into mongodb? my package.json  does not have a mongodb in dependencies.

Comment: yes , the error might be because of unstable version

Comment: do i have to add a mongodb dependency in my package.json file ?